# Ruby - Write into nested array

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I'm trying to scrape information about new album releases of a site, and I'm handling this via Nokogiri. The idea would be to create a nice array that would contain items like so

```
[ 
  0 => ['The Wall', 'Pink Floyd', '1979'], 
  1 => ['Led Zeppelin I', 'Led Zeppelin', '1969']
 ]
```

This is my current code. I'm a total ruby newbie so any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

```
@events = Array.new()
# for every date we encounter
doc.css("#main .head_type_1").each do |item|

  date = item.text

  # get every albumtitle
  doc.css(".albumTitle").each_with_index do |album, index|
    album = album.text
    @events[index]['album'] = album
    @events[index]['release_date'] = date
  end

  #get every artistname
  doc.css(".artistName").each do |artist|
    artist = artist.text
    @events[index]['artist'] = artist
  end

end

puts @events
```

P.S. the format of the page I'm trying to scrape is a bit weird:

```
<tr><th class="head_type_1">20 October 1989</th></tr>
<tr><td class="artistName">Jean Luc-Ponty</td><td class="albumTitle">Some example album</td></tr>
<tr><td class="artistName">Some Other Artist</td><td class="albumTitle">Some example album</td></tr>
<tr><td class="artistName">Some Other Artist</td><td class="albumTitle">Some example album</td></tr>
<tr><th class="head_type_1">29 October 1989</th></tr>
<tr><td class="artistName">Some Other Artist</td><td class="albumTitle">Some example album</td></tr>
```

When I try to run this within the ruby interpreter I get the following errors:

```
get_events.rb:25:in `block (2 levels) in <main>': undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from /Users/adrian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/nokogiri-1.5.5/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:239:in `block in each'
from /Users/adrian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/nokogiri-1.5.5/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:238:in `upto'
from /Users/adrian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/nokogiri-1.5.5/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:238:in `each'
from get_events.rb:23:in `each_with_index'
from get_events.rb:23:in `block in <main>'
from /Users/adrian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/nokogiri-1.5.5/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:239:in `block in each'
from /Users/adrian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/nokogiri-1.5.5/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:238:in `upto'
from /Users/adrian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/nokogiri-1.5.5/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:238:in `each'
from get_events.rb:18:in `<main>'
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: added error output and question :)

Comment: When you add an error message for a code of that complexity, you should add the line numbers to the code. Do you think anyone would go through the code to do all the work for you?

Comment: Wouldn't that make copy pasting impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't wrap my head around your solution but after playing around a little I came up with this.

```
require 'pp'
require 'nokogiri'

str = %Q{
<tr><th class="head_type_1">20 October 1989</th></tr>
<tr><td class="artistName">Jean Luc-Ponty</td><td class="albumTitle">Some album</td></tr>
<tr><td class="artistName">Some Other Artist</td><td class="albumTitle">Some album</td></tr>
<tr><td class="artistName">Some Other Artist</td><td class="albumTitle">Some album</td></tr>
<tr><th class="head_type_1">29 October 1989</th></tr>
<tr><td class="artistName">Some Other Artist</td><td class="albumTitle">Some album</td></tr>
}

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(str)
date = ""
result = []

doc.xpath("//tr").each do |tr|
  children = tr.children
  if children.first["class"] == "head_type_1"
    date = children.first.content
  else
    artist, album = children.map {|c| c.content}
    result << {album: album, artist: artist, date: date}
  end
end

pp result
```

Outputs:

`[{:album=>"Some album", :artist=>"Jean Luc-Ponty", :date=>"20 October 1989"},

  {:album=>"Some album", :artist=>"Some Other Artist", :date=>"20 October 1989"},

  {:album=>"Some album", :artist=>"Some Other Artist", :date=>"20 October 1989"},

  {:album=>"Some album", :artist=>"Some Other Artist", :date=>"29 October 1989"}]`

Not exactly what you were asking for but maybe a little more Ruby idiomatic and I'm sure you can modify it if needed.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to achieve, and had almost gotten there but for a small error. Thank you very much for your interest!

Comment: And the unspoken message of the code is that there are no other artists besides Jean Luc-Ponty. :-)

Answer (score -1):

The index variable is undefined on your second `each`.

Comment: This is not it, I've tried doc.css(".artistName").each_with_index do |artist, index|- same output